# Cypher query to analyse a dependency system

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to create a query in order to analyse a package dependency graph.
There are packages of different types(hotfix,featurepack,servicepack).

```
package-A --DEPENDS_ON--> package-B
package-A --DEPENDS_ON--> package-F
package-B -- DEPENDS_ON --> package-C
package-B --> DEPENDS_ON --> package-D
package-B -- DEPENDS_ON --> package-E
package-D --> DEPENDS_ON --> package-J
package-E --DEPENDS_ON--> package-H
package-F --REPLACES--> package-E
package-K --REPLACES--> package-F  // package-K is not a dependency of A
```

The graph can really be complex in therm of node depth.
Currently I try to use the query below but it doesn't work.

```
START n = node(1501) // package A
MATCH n-[:DEPENDS_ON*]->b
WHERE NOT(b<-[:REPLACES*]-())    // an indirect dependency package is replaced.
// so it has to be filtered but, the replacing package must be a dependency of A.
RETURN DISTINCT b, b.full_name, b.created?
ORDER BY b.created?
```

I would like to get the list of packages below:
B,F,C,D,J

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a faster approach which works well in my case.

```
MATCH p-[DEPENDS_ON*]->()-[:REPLACES*]->()-[:DEPENDS_ON*0..]->r 
WITH p, collect(r) AS replaces 
MATCH p-[:DEPENDS_ON*]->d 
WHERE p.name = 'A' AND NOT (d IN replaces) 
RETURN DISTINCT d, d.name
```

@Lisa your query helped me a lot in my learning of Cypher. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You might change the filter condition in your Where clause to this,

```
WHERE NOT(b<-[:DEPENDS_ON*0..]-()<-[:REPLACES*]-()<-[:DEPENDS_ON*]-n)
```

That would filter out all of the b that are replaced by a package which is a descendant of the package A, plus all of the descendants of b,

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Actually it returned only the first level packages and not indirectly depending packages. Also it took too much time (around 63000 millisecond).

Comment: I can see the performance is poor because of so many variable length path patterns. If you know some lengths in advance, specifying fixed lengths would improve the performance. Not sure I understand the problem of only getting the direct depending packages as it does return the expected result for your sample. I create a console here so you can see the query and result. http://console.neo4j.org/r/66ng0. Perhaps you get the problem by applying the query on the different data set?

Comment: Thank you very much for the great example you have provided. Actually, I'm having problems applying it on my real use case. I can't understand what is the reason which makes my result contain only first level packages.

Comment: Your query works fine, but it was me who took time to validate the result from my database. Thanks again.